How to get 1 column of formulas to match the same size as another column
Context: This is my table in Sheet 1. 
Column D and E both use data validation with a dropdown. Column F automatically populates based on the combination from both Column D and E. The main thing is that column E relies on column D for data validation because column D is a category and column E is a sub-category.
I do this by mapping each category to a name range, which contains all sub-categories for that category. However, since I am allowing the user to choose multiple categories (multi-select) for each entry - see the both rows, column D (the delimiter is ';') - this has made things much more complicated. I now parse each input in column D into an array of categories and concatenate the lists of sub-categories they map to together. The issue is that it does not allow me to put this directly into the cells for column E. Hence, I map the output to a row in Sheet 2.

So row 2, from column E onwards contains each subcategory for row 2 in Sheet 1. I simply take this row of cells in Sheet 2 as the data validation - when the table grows in Sheet 1, it knows itself which row to pick. The issue is that I must have this formula for the entire column E in Sheet 2 =IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTSPLIT(GetSubcategories(Table1[@DVCAT]), {","}), "_", ","), "") for this to work - the formula is only in column E and spills into other cells. It does not automatically add this formula below when the table in Sheet 1 grows - note that GetSubcategories is just a macro function.
So if I only had the formula in row 2 and 3 column E Sheet 2 and I added a new entry, then whatever my category input, my dropdown would not populate. Here is the data validation for column E:=INDIRECT("Sheet2!E" & ROW() & ":BU" & ROW()).

covert sheet1 to a table, then change the formula to refer to the table data instead of the cell reference. When the table expands/contracts the formulas in sheet2 will likewise expand/contract.

Does column 2 also need to be a table? I have changed sheet1 into a table and made the formula refer to the table. But then the formula still needs to be applied to the whole of column 2.

In short column 2 would not be in a table. I can't explain why, I just know that it will fail having tried it myself. The formula in column2 just in one cell would be something like =Table1[Column1]. There should be many tutorials of this on the web if you search for it.

I think I have followed exactly as you have said. Sheet 1 contains a table. Then I clicked one cell in sheet 2 and wrote a formula like =SomeFunction(Table1[@Column3])
and it works for this cell. But adding a new entry in the table does not copy the formula to the cell below.

Get rid of the @ in your formula

That breaks my function. My formula is a bit more complex and involves the Table1[Column1] term. This is because @ limits it to the specific row which is what I want.

I suggest you edit your question with more context adding screenshots/tables of data and expected results. Please also include what you have tried and the exact errors. Otherwise, you will not get any further responses.

No problem, just edited now. Let me know if you need further clarification.
